# Сlasses up-to-date check failed после обновления IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, update

После обновления IDEA все проекты посыпались и летит ошибка. Как её побороть?
Проект изначально создавался с Maven.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Classes up-to-date check: classes up-to-date check failed

circlet.platform.api.ClientSupportFlag
circlet.platform.api.ClientSupportFlag$Companion.getNewChatPersonalArenas()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А можно описание и сообщение об ошибки в текстовом виде в тело вопроса вложить?

Comment: было бы еще неплохо среду описать. насколько понимаю вы работаете с Gradle?

Comment: *"изначально создавался"* ... Сейчас он также на Maven работает?

Comment: Да, также на Maven.