# Сlasses up-to-date check failed после обновления IntelliJ IDEA не запускаются проекты

Tags: java, intellij-idea

После обновления **IDEA** все проекты посыпались и летит ошибка. Как её побороть? Проект изначально создавался с **Maven**.
Есть схожий вопрос, но ответ так и не получен.

[image: Моё фото]

```
Classes up-to-date check: classes up-to-date check failed

circlet.platform.api.ClientSupportFlag
circlet.platform.api.ClientSupportFlag$Companion.getNewChatPersonalArenas()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сlasses up-to-date check failed после обновления IntelliJ IDEA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353166/%d0%a1lasses-up-to-date-check-failed-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-intellij-idea)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса